max is Slantly differentiable function
I am reading the proof that the function $\Bbb{R}^n \ni v\mapsto \max(0,v) \in \Bbb{R}^n$ is slantly differentiable. The definition is: the function $F: \Bbb{R}^n\mapsto \Bbb{R}^n$ is slantly differentiable at $y$ if there exists a neighbourhood $B_{\epsilon}(y)$ and the function $G:B_{\epsilon}(y)\mapsto \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^n)$ satisfying $\lim_{\mathbf{d}\rightarrow 0} \frac{\|F(y+\mathbf{d})-F(y)-G(y+\mathbf{d})(\mathbf{d})\|}{\|\mathbf{d}\|}=0$.
However, I don't understand the proof in the book which tells that for any $z\in B_{\epsilon}$ we have that $(G(z))_{ii}=1$ if $v_i\ge 0$ and 0 if $v_i<0$. I understand why it is true when $v_i\neq 0$. However, in case when $v_i=0$, I don't see why it is true. I attach the photo of the proof in this post and if someone could clarify I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much in advance.

